# How to pass a prop back from child to parent in onclick handler and then to another component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am passing a function to a grandchild (SingleProject) from my parent (App) that opens a model. The grandchild just renders an li in the child (Gallery) that show a list of images(coming from the grandchild). I am trying to get the object from props on the grandchild, pass it back to App, and then through to the modal (Modal) to display the information about the image. The objects that hold the info about the images are stored in a service (module.exports). The openModal function is what is being passed along to the grandchild. The closeModal will be passed to the modal. I am having problems with this. Any help would be appreciated.

//APP (Parent)

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);

this.state = {
  open: false,
  projects: Service,
  selectedProject: Service[0]
}

    console.log('selectedProject: ', this.state.selectedProject)
}

closeModal(event) {
this.setState({open: false});
console.log('app: ', this.state.open);
}

openModal(event) {
this.setState({open: true});
console.log('app: ', this.state.open);
}

render() {
const show = {
  display: 'block'
};

const hide = {
  display: 'none'
};
return (
  <div>
    <div             style={this.state.open === false ? hide : show}>
      <Modal
        value={this.state.open}
        closeModal={this.closeModal}
        project={this.state.selectedProject}
      />
    </div>
    <Header />
    <Intro />
    <WhatIDo />
    <WhoIAm />
    <Gallery
      value={this.state.open}
      projects={this.state.projects}
      openModal={this.openModal}
    />
    <Contact />
    <Footer />
  </div>
 );
}
}
```

//GALLERY (child)

```
const Gallery = (props) => {
console.log('props: ', props)
const projectItems = props.projects.map(project => {
return (
  <SingleProject
    key={project.name}
    project={project}
    openModal={props.openModal}
  />
);
});

return (
<div className="gallery">
  <h3>My Work</h3>
  <ul>{projectItems}</ul>
</div>
);
}
```

//SINGLEPROJECT (grandchild)

```
const SingleProject = (props) => {
return (
<li className="gallery-images">
  <img
    src={props.project.img}
    onClick={props.openModal}
  />
</li>
);
}
```

//MODAL (Modal)

```
const Modal = (props) => {
return(
<div className="modal">
  <div
    className="modal-close"
    onClick={props.closeModal}
  />
  <ModalDesc project={props.project} />
</div>
);
}
```

//SERVICE

```
module.exports = [
{
name: 'xxx',
img: '.././images/gallery/xxx',
link: 'xxx',
tech: 'AngularJS, jQuery, HTML, CSS, PostgreSQL, Node.js, Gulp, Express.js',
desc: 'A clone of the Texas restaurant Dixie Chicken\'s website featuring a 
backend and some parallax effects. This site is not fully responsive.'
},
{
name: 'xxx',
img: '.././images/gallery/xx',
link: 'xxx',
tech: 'AngularJS, jQuery, HTML, CSS, PostgreSQL, Node.js, Gulp, Express.js',
desc: 'A fully responsive clone of the E-commerce website Stance. This was a 
group project. I did the set up of the backend, the endpoints, the frontend 
state management, the directives, most of the SQL files, the single products 
view, the login view, the account view, and the register view.'
},
{
name: 'xxx',
img: '.././images/gallery/xxx',
link: 'xxx',
tech: 'AngularJS, jQuery, HTML, CSS',
desc: 'A fully responsive site for The Battlefield Pilot Club.'
}
];
```

Comment: What happens with your current code ? Do you have any error ?

Comment: When I try to pass the selectedProject piece of state through to the grandchild, update it, and pass it back to the App (either with another function or with the openModal function) I get an error saying that selectedProject is undefined.

Comment: @ aurelienshz Uncaught ReferenceError: project is not defined -- *not defined....not undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you need correctly, you want to pass the `project` information to the `openModal` method

You just have to make a small edit to the `SingleProject` component

```
const SingleProject = (props) => {
  return (
    <li className="gallery-images">
      <img
       src={props.project.img}
       onClick={() => props.openModal(props.project)}
      />
   </li>
  );
}
```

and then in your `openModal` method you can set the `selectedProject`;

```
openModal(project) {
  this.setState({
    open: true,
    selectedProject: project,
  }, () => {
    console.log('app: ', this.state.open); // this will print "true"
  });
  console.log('app: ', this.state.open); // this will print "false"
}
```

#### Explanation:

1. Instead of passing `props.onClick` to the `onClick` prop of `<img/>` we wrap it with an arrow function that will invoke `props.onClick` with the `project` object
2. When you're logging the state in the `openModal` method, if you want it to print `true` you'll need to print it in the callback to the `setState` method since the `setState` call does not immediately set the state of the class but rather, react will batch the updates. [official documentation for the same here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Using bind is ugly in terms of readability and performance. It would be much better to declare a one-line arrow function : `onClick={() => props.openModal(props.project)}`

Comment: However you're right regarding the fact that the onClick handler need to receive the project data as props. @OP : in React apps, it is very common to have children call handlers with data related to the event that happened (in your case, such data is the project object related to the image that was clicked).

Comment: @aurelienshz is correct, i've edited my answer to reflect the same

Comment: @Raghudevan Shankar You got it, that is what I am trying to do. I'm trying to update the selectedProject property on the state in the App to send it through to the modal to update the contents of the modal with the correct info passed back from the picture that is clicked on the SingleProject view. I originally tried to set it to null but it throws an immediate ReferenceError saying that selectedProject is not defined, so I just set it to the first object in the Service array (Service[0]).

Comment: @Raghudevan Shankar and aurelienshz When I try to do it the way you explained, I am still getting a ReferenceError: project is not defined at App.openModal at onClick. Should I study up on Redux and just try to implement that? This is the first React app I've built on my own without a tutorial. Thank you both for your help so far. React is really hard, but I think once I get it it will be rewarding.

Comment: @Raghudevan Shankar I finally got it passing back to the App. I didn't see that you added project as a parameter to openModal, and I neglected to put it there. Thanks for your help! One question - what exactly is adding the function call to <img/> doing? I know it's calling the function, but why does that work and not onClick={props.openModal(project)} which I tried last night?

Comment: Because `onClick={props.openModal(props.project)}` is calling the `props.openModal` function as soon as the component is rendered, whereas `onClick={() => props.openModal(props.project)` is actually declaring an anonymous arrow function which *will be* called when the user clicks on the image (you're actually declaring an event handler, and, on the same line, passing it as prop to the `<img />` component).

Comment: @aurelienshz Great, that makes sense. Thank you for your help!